# How do I access object properties in a for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, properties

I can't find anything that explains clearly what is wrong and what I should do.

I have this array:

```
const pages = [
{ 
    url: "/",
    page: 'pages/home.html',
    title: "Home" },
{ 
    url: "/recordings",
    page:'pages/recordings.html',
    title: "Recordings" },
{ 
    url: "/editions",
    page: 'pages/editions.html',
    title: "Editions" },
{ 
    url: "/videos",
    page: 'pages/videos.html',
    title: "Videos" },
]
```

I'm trying to loop it through with a for loop. page.url returns "undefined" in the console. But the "Test URL" console log returns a url string as expected. Why? What do I do? I want the page.url in the foor loop.

```
console.log("Pages: " + pages)
console.log("Test URL: " + pages[1].url)
for (page in pages) {

    console.log("Page: " + page)
    console.log("Page URL: " + page.url)
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that when you console.log `page` you get the index, not the object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [`for ... of` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), where you get the element of the array instead of the index by using a [`for ... in` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```js
const pages = [{ url: "/", page: 'pages/home.html', title: "Home" }, { url: "/recordings", page: 'pages/recordings.html', title: "Recordings" }, { url: "/editions", page: 'pages/editions.html', title: "Editions" }, { url: "/videos", page: 'pages/videos.html', title: "Videos" }];

for (var page of pages) {
    console.log("Page: " + page.page);
    console.log("Page URL: " + page.url);
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

for..in is a method for iterating over "enumerable" properties of an object.

With arrays using for..in reveals the indexes:

```js
const pages=[{url:"/",page:'pages/home.html',title:"Home"},{url:"/recordings",page:'pages/recordings.html',title:"Recordings"},{url:"/editions",page:'pages/editions.html',title:"Editions"},{url:"/videos",page:'pages/videos.html',title:"Videos"}]

for (let index in pages) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(pages[index].page);
}
```

for..of can be used to iterate over "iterable" collections. This acts like a `.forEach()` function:

```js
const pages=[{url:"/",page:'pages/home.html',title:"Home"},{url:"/recordings",page:'pages/recordings.html',title:"Recordings"},{url:"/editions",page:'pages/editions.html',title:"Editions"},{url:"/videos",page:'pages/videos.html',title:"Videos"}]

for (let page of pages) {
  console.log(page);
  console.log(page.page);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

page would be index here...

```
console.log("Pages: " + pages)
console.log("Test URL: " + pages[1].url)
for (page in pages) {

    console.log("Page: " + pages[page])
    console.log("Page URL: " +pages[page].url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because `for in` is meant to iterate through a key, value object. `page` is just the key of the array which is 0,1,2,3,.. so you would need to do

```
console.log("Pages: " + pages)
console.log("Test URL: " + pages[1].url)

for (var key in pages) {

    console.log("Page: " + pages[key])
    console.log("Page URL: " + pages[key].url)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the first case you are accesing the first element of the array, and in that element access the property with the '.url':

```
console.log("Test URL: " + pages[1].url)
```

on the second case you get undefined because:

> The for...in statement iterates over the enumerable properties of an object. For each distinct property, statements can be executed.

pages is a **array** not a **object**, you need to iterate over the **array**, you can use **foreach** for that:

```
pages.forEach( function (page)
{
   console.log("Page: " + page)
   console.log("Page URL: " + page.url)
});
```

hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When we iterate array of objects(as you are trying) using for/in statement loop for each iteration it returns index that's why you are not getting the result as you are expecting. Following are the code which solve your problem.

```
for (page in pages) {   
  console.log("Page: " + page)//here it will print index
  console.log("Page URL: " + page.url)
}
```